# Remove the page title from the taskbar, but not the tabs

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar, firefox

Is there a setting, tweak, script, plugin or whatever that allows me to remove the active page title from the Windows XP task bar, but at the same time keep the titles of all pages in the tabs?

So, I want to keep this title:
[image: clipped screenshot of Firefox 4 highlighting a page title in the tab bar]

But, I'd ideally like this one to just be reset to "Mozilla Firefox":
[image: clipped screenshot of Win XP highlighting the page title in the app box for Firefox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your window title with [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/nightly-tester-tools/).

There is also [Customize Titlebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/customize-titlebar/) but you have to manually edit some files in .xpi package to work with firefox 4. And it may cause some troubles because it is not natively compatible with firefox 4.

Comment: Did my answer come helpful?

Comment: Yes it did (the slowness was because I had to wait until I had some down-time at work to play with), but it's a slightly over-the-top solution for just the functionality I need, but will work well enough for now. For future reference, commenting on your own post *doesn't* notify the asker - you'd need to comment on the question for that to work.

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation to do it :).

Answer (score -1):

This might be a little more than you want to spend, but Windows 7 does this quite well. The Home Premium upgrade is $129.99 and if you have a fairly modern system and at least 2GB of RAM, I think you'll enjoy that tweak among others without having to load too many auxiliary programs to get the same functionality under XP.

;)

Comment: I know Win7 does this well, I have three machines running it at home, but *at work* I'm stuck with Win XP. This isn't really an answer to my question, but is just a  "get a better computer" comment...

Comment: It would have been a different answer had you mentioned that the machine was not your personal machine. I thought you might be pleased with a Windows 7 upgrade (not new pc) since the experience would expand outside of firefox. It's all about context @DMA57361

Comment: @Dustin - while context is important, "change your OS" is almost *never* the right answer, and especially not for such a trivial issue as this that, one that is wholly within the control of the program, and a program that is specifically designed to be user modifiable. And suggesting a change of OS implies my current OS *cannot* achieve this - which is incorrect - as such, this answer is **unhelpful** whether it's my own computer or not.

Comment: @DMA57361 - I apologize, I should've read the faq or something because I didn't realize that there is only one possible solution for every question. I will keep that in mind when trying to answer future questions.

I'm really nervous about this guy that asked "how do I change my wallpaper in XP?" - I might be wrong if I tell him to right-click on the desktop and hit properties because he could go to the control panel through the start menu…

Comment: I never said it was impossible to do this with firefox or with Windows XP, but simply suggested Win7HP might be a nice choice if you would like that aesthetic system-wide. While that may not be the route that you want to take because it is a company machine or you really like XP, it would do what you wanted - and much more and I relayed that was a stretch. If you look at how I prefaced my answer, I acknowledged that Win7 was a stretch…

Comment: @Dustin, The fact that you had to preface your answer, and even add a joke smiley to the end, implies to me that you *knew* this answer wasn't really helpful when you posted it. But ultimately the bottom line is that I simply think your answer isn't useful or helpful, which is what the downvote button is for, and unlike some users I like to let people know why I downvote them when possible.

Comment: @DMA57361 I always have the conversation about upgrading to 7 when I hear people talking about features that XP does not have, not as a solution to a single problem, but because when I dig deeper, they have other things they would like their OS to do or have unknown benefits that they may find during an upgrade. Fortunately, 7 does run well on a wide variety of machines and frequently breathes new life into older computers extending the life of he machine itself and the user is surprisingly satisfied by the upgrade. Obviously that is not sensible for a work pc, it may work well for home.