# Remove "- Mozilla Firefox" from title?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

You know, this "Mozilla Firefox" appearing on each lines when you hover Firefox taskbar icon? I find this totally useless!

I'm talking about this:

[image: this]

Comment: That's Windows doing that, it's not FF specific. The task bar preview is just showing you the title of the window, which is usually "Current Document - Name of Program".  Open Notepad and you'll see the same thing, and that it matches the Notepad window title.  Firefox just doesn't show it's title bar, so it's not as obvious; and (for example) IE11 behaves the same way.

Comment: Check out this related SU question: [How to make the program name appear in the titlebar](http://superuser.com/questions/832180/windows-7-how-to-make-the-program-name-appear-in-the-titlebar)

Comment: The " - Mozilla Firefox" suffix is not done by Windows, but rather by Firefox itself, which simply creates the Window title by using the web page title and adding " - Mozilla Firefox" to it.

Comment: +1 While [this older post](http://superuser.com/q/187773/109256) asks differently but shares similar answer, the suggested add-on is either outdated or intended for different uses. Hence, I see this as relatively new question.

Answer (score 4):

> **This answer was originally written for Firefox Legacy. Additional information for Firefox Quantum may be found at below.**

[FireTitle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firetitle/) is an add-on for Firefox that can rename or remove the program name "Mozilla Firefox" from the program window. This may also remove the program name from the task bar.

Follow these steps to setup:

1. After installing the add-on, restart Firefox.
2. Go to **Tools** > **FireTitle** to open "FireTitle Options" window. Else, accessed from **Add-ons Manager** > **Extensions** > **FireTitle** and click on **Preferences** button.
3. To hide the program name "Mozilla Firefox", look under **Current Window** and edit **Title Pattern** field from `ntm` to `nt` only.
4. Click **OK** button to save the changes. This will hide the program name from window title and also in the task bar.

The following screenshot combo shows the difference for step 3.

[image: FireTitle Options before and after changes]

Tested using Firetitle 0.5.5-1.1-signed.1-signed.1-signed in Firefox 47 on Linux and task bar in Xfce environment. This will likely work similarly with Firefox in Windows, but I can't confirm if the same applies to the task bar in Windows.

### For Firefox Quantum (version 57+)

[Crappy Firetitle](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/crappy-firetitle/) is the newer add-on for Firefox Quantum, but does not work like the legacy add-on. So far, none of recent add-ons could remove the program name "Mozilla Firefox" in title bar, due to limitation of WebExtensions API.

Comment: Thank you @clearkimura for your nice answer. I'm sorry I can't upvote it for now because of my too low reputation. I wasn't aware of the FireTile Add-on. I'm using another one which does the same : https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/customize_titlebar_v2/

With both add-ons, it works well for the title in window program itself, but unfortunately not in the titles when hovering the firefox taskbar button :(

Comment: @Nigeber According to [this older post](http://superuser.com/q/285647/109256), the accepted answer noted that the original version of Customize Titlebar seemed to have worked in Windows XP. Then again, I suppose v2 didn't work in Windows 7 based on your comment.

Comment: Both original and current version work for the window itself, but won't apply to the taskbar list. Thank you anyway !